# What is $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=1}^n 0^{1/m}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is value of the following limit or does the limit exist?

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=1}^n 0^{~1/m} $$

Comment: your nickname would be much nicer as 01000101 ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Zero to (something >0) is always zero, so $\forall m:\  0^{1/m}=0$. The (finite) sum is zero for all $n$ and the limit is zero.

EDIT:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^n 0^{~1/m}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^n 0=
\lim_{n\to\infty}n0=
\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.
$$

Comment: I don't know... This is an infinite series. Setting $a_m = 0^{1/m}$ we have $\lim a_m = 0^0 = 1 \not = 0$ so the series diverges?

Comment: $0^0 \neq 1$ in the general case. It is indefinite.

Comment: $\sum_{m=1}^\infty$ is **by definition** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^n$. And you can't freely exchange $\lim$ and sum!

Comment: Think of it in a different way. Let's note $b_m = \sum_{m=1}^n 0^{~1/m}$. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, b_{m} = 0$. So basically you want $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$. It is $0$.

Comment: I see. So in fact we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}0^{1/n}=0$.

Comment: @01000100, true. But *you can't freely exchange lim and sum*.

Comment: @01000100: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}0^{1/n}=0 \not = 1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(1/n)}^0$. This tells you something interesting about $f(x,y)=x^y$ near $(0,0)$.